# How to pass command line arguments to batch file from c#

Tags: .net, process, batch-file, processstartinfo

I want to execute a batch file from c#.net code.
A batch file may take unknown number of the command line arguments.
I want to pass these arguments from c# code.

How this can be achieved through c#?

Edit :
I have written following code

```
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath);
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psi.Arguments = "some value";
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = psi;
    proc.Start();
```

Comment: This can be found all over the internet. 485,000 results for "c# batch file parameters".

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: @YoryeNathan; The purpose of StackOverflow is to ask programming questions. Read the FAQ, if you think your comment is appropriate

Comment: @AMissico Don't you agree that one should invest several minutes into research, at the very least, before posting a question about something? How would you react if someone posted a question `How to exit a loop in the middle?` - that's an automatic "oh, come on!"

Comment: @YoryeNathan; No, I absolutely do not agree.

Comment: @YoryeNathan; My reaction would be, "what kind of loop?"

Comment: @YoryeNathan; No, but I am senior, lead, and mentor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start-vbnet for a good introduction. Specifically, see the "Run executable" example at the bottom.

Here is the search query I used http://www.bing.com/search?q=command+line+parameters+process+start, if you need more examples.

Comment: I got the answer. To pass the multiple arguments I just set used following code line. ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath);
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    psi.Arguments = "value1" + "value2" + "value3";

Comment: @sagar You need spaces between each argument. You can use `string.Join(" ", values)` to easily join a collection of data, with a certain delimiter. However, in the example you provided in your last comment, you can simply do `psi.Arguments = "value1 value2 value3;`